# Data Bind RouterLink (Angular 2) - Got interpolation ({{}}) where expression was expected at column 3

Tags: javascript, angular, routes, angular2-routing

I'm having some problems passing data to my routerLink. Here is what I'm trying to do: (this input is inside a ngFor, I need to change the route when the id reaches 4)

```
 <input type="button" class="btn-cards" [ngClass]="getStyle(negociacao)"  [routerLink]="['/{{negociacao.rota}}', negociacao.id]" value="{{negociacao.status}}">
```

The error I'm getting is the following one:

> Got interpolation ({{}}) where expression was expected at column 3

Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You should not be using `{{}}`(interpolation) inside `routerLink` directive.

```
[routerLink]="['/', negociacao.rota, negociacao.id]"
```